# Modified vs Last_x0020_Modified

Tags: 2013, list, spfield, item

Which is the difference between the fields:
**Modified** and **Last_x0020_Modified** 
in a SharePoint list item ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Modified: Identifies a field that contains the last modified date and time information that is associated with the specified SharePoint Foundation object.
- Last_x0020_Modified: Identifies a field that contains version control
  information for the last modified version of the specified SharePoint
  Foundation list object.

The ‘Modified’ column as we see in the lists or document libraries provides us with the information as to the date and time the item was last modified.

There is more nuances added to this column. The ‘Modified’ column not only keeps track of the when the user has made any changes to the item, but it also records if there are updates or changes to the items in a list or document library by any in-built background jobs such as the scheduling jobs.

This plays a vital role as in some situations there may be a requirement were we are required to track only changes made explicitly by the user to the item in the list or the document library.

The ‘Modified’ column is denoted internally as ‘Modified’ and the ‘Last Modified’ is internally denoted as ‘Last_x0020_Modified’ and is hidden from the views. You can check out the differences by using the U2U caml query tool or the Imtech Fields explorer.

http://www.mstechblogs.com/shailaja/difference-between-the-%E2%80%98modified%E2%80%99-and-the-%E2%80%98last-modified%E2%80%99-columns-or-fields-in-sharepoint-2007/

http://benhuang.blogspot.no/2009/07/sharepoint-modified-field-and-last.html